# Property not found in class - Flow & React

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to leverage Flow and get it working nicely with a react component of mine. However I am getting:

> client/search-container.jsx:18   18:     this.handleSearchSubmit =
>   this.handleSearchSubmit.bind(this);
>                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `handleSearchSubmit`. Property not found in   18: class SearchContainer extends
>   React.Component {
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SearchContainer

The component I have set up is as followed:

```
// @flow

import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import SearchForm from './search-form';

type Props = {
  onSearchUpdate: Function,
}


class SearchContainer extends React.Component {
  props: Props;


  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSearchSubmit = this.handleSearchSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSearchSubmit(searchTerm: {address: string, lat: number, lng: number}): void {
    this.props.onSearchUpdate(searchTerm);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchBox">
        <SearchForm onSearchSubmit={this.handleSearchSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// SearchContainer.propTypes = {
//   onSearchUpdate: PropTypes.func,
// };

export default SearchContainer;
```

You'll see previously I was making use of the propTypes at the bottom of my class. Questions:

1. Does my class set up look correct?
2. Why is flow complaining that property `handleSearchSubmit` is not found and the same too with the name of my class name `SearchContainer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow treats methods on classes as read-only. Thus, the line

```
this.handleSearchSubmit = this.handleSearchSubmit.bind(this);
```

triggers a flow error. Here is a relevant github issue: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1517

There's a couple of workarounds to deal with this. I generally handle it this way:

```
constructor(props: Props) {
  super(props);

  const self: Object = this
  self.handleSearchSubmit = this.handleSearchSubmit.bind(this)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello I feel like that @TLadd answer is a hack.

Flow is asking for the type of handleSearchSubmit and it does not find it
you just need to add this below below the method definition

```
  handleSearchSubmit: <your type>;
```

This is the final code

```
// @flow

import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import SearchForm from './search-form';

type Props = {
  onSearchUpdate: Function,
}


class SearchContainer extends React.Component {
  props: Props;
  // ->>>
  handleSearchSubmit: <your type>;
  // <---
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSearchSubmit = this.handleSearchSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSearchSubmit(searchTerm: {address: string, lat: number, lng: number}): void {
    this.props.onSearchUpdate(searchTerm);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchBox">
        <SearchForm onSearchSubmit={this.handleSearchSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// SearchContainer.propTypes = {
//   onSearchUpdate: PropTypes.func,
// };

export default SearchContainer;
```